# How to stop asynchronous thread after 5 seconds of running

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

Have to create thread and run it for 5 seconds, then I want to stop. How can I do that?

I can't do anything with time/milliseconds.

THX.

Comment: You want to run for 5 seconds, without doing anything with time? Wha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`AsyncTask.cancel(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) method.

Comment: This looks promissing. And, can I use postDelayed to cancel my AsyncTask after 5 seconds? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Threading in java is cooperative - you can not forcefully stop a thread. What you can do is signal it to stop (call interrupt() or raise a flag) and then the code willingly stops.

So:

1. Start running your worker thread. Inside it repeatedly (inside main working loop) check for `isInterrupted()` AND catch any `InterruptedExceptions` - exit the thread in this case.
2. Start a TimerTask to run for 5 sec, then call `interrupt()` on the worker thread.

**Update:** poster explained that he already has a working code, he just needs to run it asynchronously without blocking UI.

Solution: setup [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and run your code inside it's `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being clear here. Here is the example I have for synchronous thread.
My function listen() runs for 5 seconds then exits. Listen() is a UDP listener...

Problem I have with this code, it stops my main thread (my phone became unresponsive) until listed() finishes its 5 seconds run. I would like to use asynchronous thread to avoid my phone freezing up. When I said I can't do anything with time, I was trying to say that I can't put some sort of timer in listen() function then measure lapsed time then exit after 5 seconds. Can't do that.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            listen();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException (Discovery) " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
};
synchronized (t) {
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join(5000); // 5 sec

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Setup `AsyncTask` and run this code inside it's `doInBackground()` method.